# Vs code source control is IDing my git hub repos as files and won't identify changes

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, source-control-explorer

I have been using vs code for a while now and haven't had any problems with it. But of late I have had to solve some merge conflict in some code that I am colabing on and my source controller is not working correctly.

For some reason it is identifying my repos as files and won't identify my changes that I make. And just all around is not working at all.

I have tried reinstalling git, vs code, system restoring my windows, and using other scm's but nothing is working and I get the exact same problem every time. I am at a complete loss and have no idea what is wrong, please I need help big time because this is infuriating and I don't know what else to try.

**please help!**

this is what my repo's look like on the source controller:

[image: repository source controller]

these are supposed to be folders but it thinks they are files. Why would it think this? also when I type in my files it won't put them in unstaged changes.

Answer (score 0):

> these are supposed to be folders but it thinks they are file

First, check the status of one of those folders in command line:

```
cd /path/to/one/folder
dir .git
git status
```

That is: is there a `.git` subfolder, and does `git status` works under that folder?

If yes, with VSCode, do create a workspace, and add that folder to the workspace.
Then check if Git does work for that folder.